# How to get dropped data as HTML from a DropEvent?

Tags: javascript, gwt, contenteditable, jsni

I am trying to create a `contenteditable` that has chip-elements inside it which should be drag & dropable. You can take a look of this poorly working thing on [my github repo](https://github.com/silentsnooc/contenteditable-textarea).

The story of how I got things working so far is another and after struggling for *days* now I was finally able to come up with a solution that seems to work in let's say 90% of all cases.

One remaining problem though is that it is possible to select text and drag & drop it inside this text area:

[image]

The selection here would be something like "`lling <div class="chip">Red Screwdriver</div> an`". In order to disallow this I see two options:

Either disallow text selection at all - which I could not succeed so far - or take a look at the drop event and check the dragged HTML content. My problem is that I don't know how I can get that. Since I only want to allow one single element being drag & dropped at a time, I could actually compare "`lling <div class="chip">Red Screwdriver</div> an`" to my dragged element:

```java
String draggedHtmlDataAsString = event.getDraggedHtmlDataAsString();

if(this.draggedElement.getHtml().equals(draggedHtmlDataAsString) == false) {
    // Don't accept data
} else {
    // Accept data
}
```

but I don't know how I can get this data from the drop event. A pure GWT/Java solution is as good as a JavaScrit/JSNI solution for me.

Any suggestions that would be much better than this are welcome.

I also tried to disallow selection but, see yourself ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

To prevent selection, add this CSS class to your widget:

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Instead of displaying text as text, you can break it down into individual tokens, each represented by an InlineLabel widget (or "span" element).

For example, you will have these tokens:

- we are selling
- Blue Screwdriver
- and
- Red Screwdriver

You add each InlineLabel to a container, setting "contenteditable" on all widgets but "draggable" only on those you allow to drag.

If you need the ability to drop new chips between any words, then each token should represent one word only. You may also prevent chips from being dropped inside a word - and allow drops only in spaces between the tokens.

Comment: I already went that road and it was a complete mess. It sounds reasonable at the beginning but as far as I can tell this gets more and more hairy and frustrating. But I am also not sure if that would prevent the user to select text inside the text area and mess up my drag and drop process after all.

Comment: I updated my answer. With the proposed approach, however, you don't need to prevent users from selecting text.

Comment: I already got exactly those lines in my css ^^ The problem is that, for whatever reason, this does not work. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: It is a nightmare that I am stuck in for a few weeks now.. Right now I am considering to give up and decide for a "mention" token like `#` that will start up a suggest-box context. This whole drag & drop thing inside `contenteditable` is the purest evilness ..

Comment: This does not work because you use TextArea, I suppose. This is why I offered a different approach.

Comment: No, actually this is a `contenteditable` div. I just called the styling `textarea`. You can't place elements inside `textarea` afaik.

Comment: You can take a look at [the ui.xml](https://github.com/silentsnooc/contenteditable-textarea/blob/master/contenteditable-client/src/main/java/com/contenteditable/modal/DemoModalView.ui.xml) and also [the implementation](https://github.com/silentsnooc/contenteditable-textarea/blob/master/contenteditable-client/src/main/java/com/contenteditable/widget/ContenteditableTextArea.java) of the contenteditable if you want.